# Equivalent of noUnusedParameters in @typescript-eslint

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'm trying to improve developers' experience of a React+TS project. I find `noUnusedLocals` and `noUnusedParameters` quite useful for the project but these rules complicate development and, especially, debug process more often than never. That's why I try to disable them on the compiler level but keep them in linter.

Apparently TypeScript Eslint plugin provides `@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars` as an alternative to `noUnusedLocals`.

But I'm struggling to find a proper alternative to `noUnusedParameters`. Which could be helpful to catch unused class properties and methods. Is there any way to catch unused parameters in linter or at least to decrease its severity on compiler level?

Comment: Unused parameters (described as "arguments") are also covered by `no-unused-vars`, per [the docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars).

Comment: @jonrsharpe can `no-unused-vars` catch unused class properties and methods? Because `noUnusedParameters` can...

Comment: Well, where could you look to find out? Also you can just lint some code that you consider non compliant and see what it says.

Comment: @jonrsharpe documentation says nothing about that. I assume it can't. I also experimented with `no-unused-vars` on the existing project but didn't get the desired behavior.

Comment: I use `noUnusedLocals` in my project, and I think it's a good idea. If you really want an unused parameter / variable, just prefix it with `_`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at each of the areas of unused code, this table summarizes how each tool can or can't detect it statically:

| Area | TypeScript | typescript-eslint |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Unused parameters | `"noUnusedParameters` | `plugin:@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars` |
| Unused `private` properties | `"noUnusedLocals"` | *(not available yet - see below)* |
| Unused `#` properties | `"noUnusedLocals"` | `no-unused-private-class-members` |
| Unused variables | `"noUnusedLocals"` | `plugin:@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars` |

There are a couple open relevant typescript-eslint issues:

- [#4571 Rule proposal: no-unused-private-class-members](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/4571): tracks creating an [extension rule](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/#extension-rules) -`plugin:@typescript-eslint/no-unused-private-class-members`- to catch unused `private` properties (and explains why this is unintuitively tricky)
- [#8218 Docs: Mention no-unused-private-class-members in no-unused-vars](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/8218): tracks mentioning this situation more in docs