# no-unused-vars for constructor params false negative

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint

I have a variable in the constructor that is un-used, but nothing seems to notice except tsc. If I run tsc it will tell me there is an un-used variable, but there does not seem to be anything I can do to make eslint recognize the un-used variable.

I have tried all the common plugins and recommendations:

```
"plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates",
"plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
"plugin:import/recommended",
"plugin:import/typescript",
"eslint:recommended"
```

My example component with an error is below:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { ApiService } from '../services/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
})
export class HomeComponent {
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}
}
```

The apiService is the one that is un-used in this case
tsc tells me:

> Property 'staffScheduleSessionService2' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6138)

Comment: you can set "noUnusedParameters": true in tsconfig

Comment: @mohitjain I know I can set that, but I dont want build errors, I want it in eslint where I can lint at will.

Comment: The error you show is being generated by TypeScript, not by ESLint.

Comment: @GOTO0 I know it is generated by TypeScript, I want the error to be generated by ESLint. That is the question.

Comment: Any update on this? I would also prefer to have this as a linting error and not as a build/run breaking build error...

Comment: It's worth mentioning that tslint is now deprecated, and essentially has merged with eslint. If I come across a solution I'll post it. Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint

Answer (score 0):

Did a bit of scouring on the web, happened to come across [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58949235/equivalent-of-nounusedparameters-in-typescript-eslint) which describes my findings.

As it turns out, there's **no equivalent** yet for unused constructor parameters or private members (TS rules 6133 and 6138).

If you're early on in a project, you can enable the ["noUnusedLocals" and "noUnusedParameters"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUnusedLocals) rules in your TS config which will keep your code clean from the get-go. Unfortunately for projects down the line, this may be problematic as it will prevent the project from compiling properly and would need the errors to be addressed.

It seems [the reason for this disconnect](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/4571) between the compiler options and ESLint rules is it's unintuitively tricky to achieve, and an autofixer becomes quite complicated.